# Should I optimize around reads or CPU time in Google App Engine

Tags: python, algorithm, google-app-engine

I'm trying to optimize my design, but it's really difficult to put things in perspective. Say I have the following cases:

A. A User has 1,000 status updates. These updates are stored in a separate entity, Statuses. I want to get a User's statuses which have a uploadDate after date X. So I do a query:

`statuses = Statuses.query(Statuses.uploadDate > X).fetch()`

B. A User has 1,000 status updates. Each User entity has a list property `list_of_status_keys`, which is a list of all keys to the user's statuses. I want to get all statuses with uploadDate after date X. So I easily get a list of statuses using `statuses = ndb.get_multi(list_of_status_keys)`. Then I loop through each one, checking the date:

```
for a_status in statuses:
  if a_status.uploadDate > X:
     myList.append(a_status)
```

I really don't know which I should be optimizing for. A query is more organized it seems, but fetching by keys is quicker. Anyone have any insight?

## UPDATE

Here's what it comes down to:
In each http request to GAE, I get all notifications and status updates for a user (just like facebook). Using Appstats, it tells me that each request costs 490 micropennies (where 1 penny = 1,000,000 micropennies).

Getting notifications and statuses is important for a user, so you can expect them to do this many times. What I'm having a hard time with is determining if this is a lot or not. I'm freaking out trying to minimize this number in any way possible. I've never run a service before, so I don't know if this is how much it should cost. Here's the math:

Each request costs 490 micropennies when no results are returned (so just for a basic query it costs 490, but on some cases when several results are returned, it could cost 10,000 mp), so for 1 penny, I can run 2040 requests, or for $1 dollar, I can run 204,000 requests.

Let's say I have 50,000 users, and each user checks for notifications 75 times a day (reasonable):

`75 requests X 490 mp per request X 50,000 users = 1,837,500,000 micropennies per day = 1837.5 pennies = 18.37 dollars per day.` (is that right?)

I've never run a large scale service before, so are these usual costs? Or is this too high? Is 490 micropennies per request high? How would I find an answer to this if it depends?

Comment: Well, do you care more about speed or about readability? In the second case, be aware that the loop can also be written as a comprehension: `[s for s in statuses if s.uploadDate > X]`.

Comment: @larsmans well readability is not an issue. I care most about cost, then speed, so long as the differences aren't major.

Comment: Saying readability is not an issue can lead to costly issues later on :) What exactly do you mean by cost? (Not familiar with GAE.)

Comment: @larsmans but what confuses me is that if the user has 100,000 status updates, a query will only get and have in memory the ones that I need, past date X. However, without a query, I'd get all 100,000 statuses and filter in memory. I'm just not sure how that works with GAE (or on any system for that matter).

Comment: a core tenet of python is dont worry about optimization until it become a problem then optimize specifically for that problem...

Comment: @JoranBeasley I guess what confuses me is that..is it ok for a machine to filter 100,000 items in memory? Is this an expensive operation, or pretty normal?

Comment: why wouldnt you `query.order_by('date').all().reversed()[:100]`  and only get the latest ones ... thats probably costly even with small rows(100k rows in memory).. (and i havent used app engine but i assume they have something like the above code )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Design A is superior.

In design A GAE will use the date to perform a keyed query. What this means is, that Appengine will automatically create an index for you on the Status table sorted by the date. Since it has an index, it will read and fetch only the records after the date you specify. This will save you a large number of reads.

In Design B you basically will have to do the indexing work yourself. Since you will need to fetch each Status and then compare its date you will have to do more work, both in terms of CPU (is cost) as in terms of performance.

**EDIT**

If your data is accessed as frequently as this, you may have other design options as well.

First you could consider combining the Status objects into StatusUpdatesPerDay. For each day you create a single instance and then append status updates to that object. This will reduce hundreds of reads into a couple of reads.

Second, since the status updates will be accessed very frequently, you can cache the Status in memcache. This will give reduce costs and latency.

Third, even if you do not optimize as above, I believe ndb has built in caching. I have never used this feature, but your actual read counts may be lower than in your calculations.

A fourth option is avoid displaying all status updates at once. Maybe the user wants to see only the last few. Then you can use query cursors to get the remainder when (and if) the user requests them.

Comment: I see what you mean. Can you check out my update and see what you think about that?

Comment: If users will be checking their status that frequently, you have other design options. I will update my answer.

Comment: So collecting the keys of all statuses and putting them in an array property of a User is just sort of like manual indexing, and this is what Google App Engine already does you're saying?

Comment: So my goal should not be to minimize queries?

Comment: No your goal should not be to minimize queries, your goal should be to minimize database reads. Each object fetched will be a database read. It does not matter if you use a query or fetch it yourself. So, if you fetch _all_ objects by keys and then only select the ones that meet your criteria, then you will do _more_ work than if you let Appengine do that for you using a query.

Comment: Ahhh I see..so a query doesn't really cost anything, it's only when the query gets results back that it costs? So if I run a query that returns 0 results, does that cost me anything?

Comment: So ya according to documentation, it's 1 read per query + 1 (small) read per entity returned