# Collecting keys vs automatic indexing in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

After enabling Appstats and profiling my application, I went on a panic rage trying to figure out how to reduce costs by any means. A lot of my costs per request came from queries, so I sought out to eliminate querying as much as possible.

For example, I had one query where I wanted to get a User's StatusUpdates after a certain date X. I used a query to fetch: `statusUpdates = StatusUpdates.query(StatusUpdates.date > X)`.

So I thought I might outsmart the system and avoid a query, but incur higher write costs for the sake of lower read costs. I thought that every time a user writes a Status, I store the key to that status in a list property of the user. So instead of querying, I would just do `ndb.get_multi(user.list_of_status_keys)`.

The question is, what is the difference for the system between these two approaches? Sure I avoid a query with the second case, but what is happening behind the scenes here? Is what I'm doing in the second case, where I'm collecting keys, just me doing a manual indexing that GAE would have done for me with queries?

In general, what is the difference between get_multi(keys) and a query? Which is more efficient? Which is less costly?

Comment: You can save a lot of "time" and money by simply leveraging memcache.

Comment: @Nix well I'm using NDB which automatically handles memcache..but I just want to get an understanding for what's happening behind the scenes here..

Comment: Please point me to the doc about NDB and auto memcache.  I'm interested to read about it.

Comment: @Nix https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the docs on billing:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing

It's pretty straightforward.  Reads are $0.07/100k, smalls are $0.01/100k, so you want to do smalls.

A query is 1 read + 1 small / entity
A get is 1 read.  If you are getting more than 1 entity back with a query, it's cheaper to do a query than reading entities from keys.

Query is likely more efficient too.  The only benefit from doing the gets is that they'll be fully consistent (whereas a query is eventually consistent).

Answer (score 1):

Storing the keys does not query, as you cannot do anything with just the keys. You will still have to fetch the Status objects from memory. Also, since you want to query on the date of the Status object, you will need to fetch *all* the Status objects into memory and compare their dates yourself. If you use a Query, appengine will fetch only the Status with the required date. Since you fetch less, your read costs will be lower.

As this is basically the same question as you have posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12484497/should-i-optimize-around-reads-or-cpu-time-in-google-app-engine), I suggest that you look at the answer I gave there.